# Insert value of one row to the value of another row? (Preferably through Eloquent)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently trying to create a code wherein the value of the one specific row is inserted into another row's same column.

For example, I have Product Type A as ProdA and it has a current quantity (curr_quantity), ProdA will be turn into ProdB after 1 week due to spoilage which means the value of ProdA's curr_quantity will be subtracted and added to the curr_quantity of ProdB, I have the code to update the curr_quantity of ProdA but it does not currently add to ProdB.

My Controller Codes:

```
$decrease = Product::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(7))
                ->where('curr_quantity', '>', 0)
                ->get();

            foreach($decrease as $dec){
            $sub = $dec->curr_quantity;

                if($dec->products_id == 1){
                    $dec->update([
                        'curr_quantity' => $dec->curr_quantity - $sub
                        ]);
                }

                if($dec->products_id == 2){
                    $dec->update([
                        'curr_quantity' => $dec->curr_quantity - $sub,
                        ]);
                }
```

In my code above it currently subtracting the curr_quantity of ProdA and ProdB and subtracting, but it's not "transferring" the value from one product to the other.

EDIT: In my current code, it's subtracting on both since ProdB is supposed to be "transferred" to ProdC. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Product Type is an FK, so Prod A is products_id == 1, B == 2 and C == 3 in the actual code.

```
[Sample]
ID | Product Type | curr_quantity
0  | Prod A       | 70
1  | Prod B       | 30
2  | Prod C       | 10 
3  | Prod A       | 90
4  | Prod B       | 05
5  | Prod C       | 05
```

After 7 days it should be like this:

```
ID | Product Type | curr_quantity
0  | Prod A       | 0
1  | Prod B       | 70
2  | Prod C       | 40 
3  | Prod A       | 0
4  | Prod B       | 90
5  | Prod C       | 10
```

Would there be a way to update the curr_quantity of ProdA and transfer it to ProdB?

Comment: You are subtracting two times at the moment. Why not simply use the following logic: `update products set curr_quantity = curr_quantity - {curr_quantity from A} WHERE products_id = B` and `update products set curr_quantity = 0 WHERE products_id = A`?

Comment: Hmm tried this out and it gave me a better understanding of the logic, but the code didn't work well since it didn't give the proper outcome yet, still experimenting tho, thanks!